# How to rotate the results JTL file of Apache JMeter output?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Apache Jmeter has the -l option for logging the results. However, it creates a single file. If the test is run for quite some time, this log file becomes huge and it takes time to process this file. Is there a way where we can rotate the log file based on file size?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343846/log4j-xml-rolling-appender-based-on-size

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link! Could you please help me with configuring the settings for JTL file?

Answer (score 1):

As of current [JMeter version 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) it is not possible, the options are in:

1. Use i.e. [`split` program](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html) to break up large .jtl file into smaller pieces. More information:

   - [How to Split Large Text File into Smaller Files in Linux](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/split-large-text-file-smaller-files-linux/)
2. Don't use .jtl results file and switch to [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) so the results would go to external database and you can interactively choose smaller chunks, perform filtering, etc. More information:

   - [Real-time results](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html)
   - [How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter Non-GUI Results](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results/)